# Animate Floating Views, which don't have a parent layout?

Tags: android, animation, service, fadeout, floating

How can I make a e.g. Fade out **animation** for a floating view that don't has a parent layout. This code works fine for everything nested inside layouts. Is there an option to make this possible for parents which are displayed in a floating service?

**Code:**

```
protected void FadeAnimation(View animationview, boolean fadein)
    {
        if(fadein){
            //Fade in Animation
            Animation animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.introfadein);
            animationFadeIn.setFillAfter(true);
            animationFadeIn.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    animationview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            animationview.setAnimation(animationFadeIn);
        } else {
            //Fade out Animation
            Animation animationFadeOut = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.introfadeout);
            animationFadeOut.setFillAfter(true);
            animationFadeOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                        animationview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                }
            });
            animationview.setAnimation(animationFadeOut);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Do you mean you've tried this on a `View` added to `WindowManager`, and it didn't work?

Comment: @MikeM. Yes that is what I tried. Didn't work.

Comment: I just got a chance to test this briefly, and yeah, you're right. It seems that `View` animations don't work on `View`s added directly to `WindowManager`. [This does](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21811425), though, if you're running on 4.0+.